# aws s3 sync --exlude option isnt recognized when run inside subprocces

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Im trying to run the [exclude](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) option run inside a python script by [subprocces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

when i run it on the shell with `sudo aws s3 sync /local_dir/ s3://bucket --exclude "*.txt" --dryrun` it work perfect, removing the text files before sync.

But when i run inside the python script i get *Unknown options: --exclude "*.txt"*

The python script is as it follows

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["sudo", "aws", "s3", "sync", "/local_dir/", "s3://bucket", '--exclude "*.txt"*',"--dryrun"])
```

Comment: I solved using os.system module instead of subproccess. I still dont know why it wont work with subproccess

Comment: You have too many quotes and you need to have only one token per list item. You want something like `subprocess.run(["sudo", "aws", "s3", "sync", "/local_dir/", "s3://bucket", "--exclude", "*.txt*", "--dryrun"])` (see how I've split the `--exclude` argument into two items and dropped the nested quotes).